# BrowserComponent / WebBrowser doesn't close when back is pressed

Tags: codenameone

I am using a WebBrowser in a form. When I press the back button, the browser doesn't close (Stays on top of the GUI), and the application keeps going back til it reach the first screen (I see the title changes)

Another issue that might be related. If I rotated the device (with the browser form open), the previous form is shown, and the browser renders on top of it.

I tested this on Android 5.0, works fine in simulator.

```
public static void showBrowser(String id) {
    final Form form = new Form("browser");
    final WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    form.setBackCommand(new Command(" ") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //show another form
            Login.show();
        }
    });
    form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    browser.setURL("http://www.google.com");
    form.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
    form.show();
}
```

Comment: Do you do something specific in Login.show? This should close implicitly

Comment: No I am not doing anything specific in `Login.show`. but I was doing something specific just before showing the form. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this issue is related to making a request just before showing the browser form.

I had a method which make a request using

`NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(request);`

This request returns "id" that I pass to `showBrowser(String id)`.

When I removed this request, the browser worked perfectly. So, as a workaround, now I show the browser form with a hardcoded link, then ***after*** showing the form(`form.show()`), I make the request and update the browser using this

`browser.setURL()` and `browser.reload()`

*I don't know how is that related, but it solved the problem.*

Comment: This is probably related to the andWait call blocking the EDT. Try using the AddToQueue without waiting in this case

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
final WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    form.setBackCommand(new Command(" ") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            browser.destroy();
            //show another form
            Login.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried `browser.destroy()` and `browser.remove()`, but I got the same behavior. I found a workaround but the original issue is still there. So, please check the answer to know how to reproduce this.